# How to add gif as a top layer to video with javaCV?

Tags: javacv

How to add gif as a top layer to video with javaCV?
I try to add GIF over a video and continuously loop. When I use ffmpeg command, everything works well.
But I have no idea how to implemet it wwith javaCV.
Any one can help me?

Comment: We can easily use the ffmpeg program from Java: http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/apidocs/org/bytedeco/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html